# formatting the output of an xquery by inserting the tags appropriately

Tags: xml, formatting, xquery

i have written the xquery but i am not getting the output formatting correct.

this is my code

```
let $doc:=(doc("hamlet.xml"))
for $y in distinct-values($doc/PLAY/ACT/SCENE/SPEECH/SPEAKER/text())
return 
<SPEAKER>
{$y}
<scene>{$doc/PLAY/ACT/SCENE/SPEECH[SPEAKER = $y]/../TITLE}</scene>
</SPEAKER>
```

The output which it is producing is of the form

```
<SPEAKER>BERNARDO<scene>
<TITLE>SCENE I.  Elsinore. A platform before the castle.</TITLE>
<TITLE>SCENE II.  A room of state in the castle.</TITLE>
</scene>
</SPEAKER>
<SPEAKER>FRANCISCO<scene>
<TITLE>SCENE I.  Elsinore. A platform before the castle.</TITLE>
</scene>
</SPEAKER>
```

the output which i want should be of the form

```
<SPEAKER>BERNARDO
<scene>SCENE I.  Elsinore. A platform before the castle.</scene>
<scene>SCENE II.  A room of state in the castle.</scene>

</SPEAKER>
<SPEAKER>FRANCISCO
<scene>SCENE I.  Elsinore. A platform before the castle.</scene>
</SPEAKER>
```

i tried a lot to get the right output, how do i do it? please help

Comment: Are your sure you want to create mixed content? I would wrap the speaker name in another element (e.g. `<name>BERNARDO</name>) to avoid mixed content whenever possible. If you have the possibility to define your own output, I would consider changing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let $doc:=(doc("hamlet.xml"))
for $y in distinct-values($doc/PLAY/ACT/SCENE/SPEECH/SPEAKER/text())
return 
<SPEAKER>
{$y}
<scene>{$doc/PLAY/ACT/SCENE/SPEECH[SPEAKER = $y]/../TITLE/text()}</scene>
</SPEAKER>
```